# Adding 2 types of parameters using java generics

Tags: java, generics

In the below program am passing 2 types parameters uisng single method.
I am getting "The operator + is undefined for the argument   type(s) T, K" while adding 2 parameters.

```
import java.util.*;
class Multipletypeparameters<T,K>{
    T obj1;
    K obj2;
    public void setting(T obj1,K obj2){
        this.obj1=obj1;
        this.obj2=obj2;
    }
    public T add(){
        //Here While adding I am getting The operator + is undefined for the argument type(s) T, K error
        return obj1 + obj2;
    }
}
public class MultipleTypeParametersExample {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        MultipleTypeParametersExample<String,String> g1=new MultipleTypeParametersExample <String,String>();
        g1.setting("A","B");
        System.out.println(g1.add());

        MultipleTypeParametersExample <Integer,Integer> g2=new MultipleTypeParametersExample <Integer,Integer>();
        g2.setting(10,10);
        System.out.println(g2.add());
    }

}
```

Comment: are you trying to add two objects together?

Comment: That's because the compiler doe not know how to use the ``+`` operator to "add" two instances of the generic types ``T`` and ``K``. Imagine you pass a ``Car`` and a ``Boat`` instance for ``T`` and ``K`` - what do you expect the ``+`` to do?! A driving boat? A swimming car? And how would the compiler know that?

Comment: Well, it is true since the `+` method is not defined for `Object`.

What should happen if you create a `MultipleTypeParametersExample<List, Set>`?

Comment: the `+` operator is defined for primitive number types and Strings only. anything else needs a method defined in an interface where the implementing class knows what to do.

Comment: then how to add , With strings I need to get output as AB and with int I need output 20

Comment: It is an interesting problem though, cause even if geneticType `T` and `K` extends `Number` (by specifying that in the generic arguments of the class) there is no easy way to implement the `+` operator. (Reffers to a problem I had with implementing `int` and `float` support for a single generic object)

Comment: @user2709752 use `T extends String` (and maybe cast the variable before concatnating) or dont use generics at all.(if String is the only genericType allowed).

Comment: Are you a C++ programmer? Generics in Java do not work the same way as templates in C++ (where this kind of thing would be possible).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is related to the fact that you use the operator `+` with objects while it is only understood by the compiler with primitive types and/or `String`.

One way to solve your problem is to propose an implementation of this operation.

Assuming that you use Java 8, your code could be something like this:

The class `Multipletypeparameters`

```
class Multipletypeparameters<T, K> {
    T obj1;
    K obj2;
    private final BiFunction<T, K, T> add;

    public Multipletypeparameters(BiFunction<T, K, T> add) {
        this.add = add;
    }
    public void setting(T obj1, K obj2) {
        this.obj1 = obj1;
        this.obj2 = obj2;
    }
    public T add(){
        return add.apply(obj1, obj2);
    }
}
```

Your test code:

```
Multipletypeparameters<String, String> g1 = new Multipletypeparameters<>((a, b) -> a + b);
g1.setting("A", "B");
System.out.println(g1.add());

Multipletypeparameters<Integer, Integer> g2 = new Multipletypeparameters<>(
    (a, b) -> a + b
);
g2.setting(10, 10);
System.out.println(g2.add());
```

**Output:**

```
AB
20
```

---

This approach applies the [**Strategy pattern**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strategy_pattern) which allows you to specify the implementation to use (the strategy to adopt) at `Runtime` but you could also make this method abstract and propose sub classes that will implement this method, as next:

```
abstract class Multipletypeparameters<T, K> {
    ...
    public abstract T add();
}
```

The implementations:

```
class MultipleStringparameters extends Multipletypeparameters<String, String> {

    @Override
    public String add() {
        return this.obj1 + this.obj2;
    }
}

class MultipleIntegerparameters extends Multipletypeparameters<Integer, Integer> {

    @Override
    public Integer add() {
        return this.obj1 + this.obj2;
    }
}
```

The test code:

```
Multipletypeparameters<String, String> g1 = new MultipleStringparameters();
g1.setting("A", "B");
System.out.println(g1.add());

Multipletypeparameters <Integer, Integer> g2 = new MultipleIntegerparameters();
g2.setting(10, 10);
System.out.println(g2.add());
```

**Output:**

```
AB
20
```

Comment: Thanks for sample code. compiled in 1.8, but getting many errors regarding a and b

Comment: if you use java 8, it should compile, they are just lambda expressions

Comment: I'd say that `BiFunction` is the way to go here. The currently accepted answer using `instanceof` looks .... ehm... not so nice (not to say "horrible").

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is that you are using language elements that you don't understand!

You see, you declared

```
public T add(){
  return obj1 + obj2;
}
```

Meaning: that method is supposed to return an object of type T. But your code tries to use the primitive-only operator + on a T and K object. That simply cant work. Because that operator only works for primitive types; and of course, even if it would work, who says that you can "adding" two *arbitrary* T and K objects would result in an object of type T?!
The only thing that would work:

```
public String asStrings(){
  return obj1.toString() + obj2.toString();
}
```

And as you actually want to add numbers; you have to look into changing your generic types into something that extends *Number*! Then you you could be calling methods like intValue() or doubleValue() on them. And then using "+" becomes possible again.

Answer (score 1):

You can change your `add` method to something like this. Note I've changed the class to a single generic type, otherwise you'd need to add more options to cater for Integer, String combos and I don't see why you would want to add different types. I find this not to be an elegant solution, and you'd be better off using a Strategy pattern where you can define what operation is performed when adding.

```
public class Example<T> {
    T obj1;
    T obj2;

    public void setting(T obj1,T obj2){
        this.obj1=obj1;
        this.obj2=obj2;
    }

    public T add(){
        if (obj1 instanceof String) {
            return (T) ((String) obj1 + (String) obj2);
        } else if (obj1 instanceof Integer) {
            return (T) ((Integer) ((Integer) obj1 + (Integer) obj2));
        } else {
            return null;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

what do you want exactly in "add" method ? I guess if your obj is `int` you want to add two numbers or you want to suffix strings. In conclusion you should check object I mean you have to use `instanceOf` keyword. For example, `obj1 instanceof String`